# Undefined index - get_option

Tags: plugins

I want to unset the css file if the checkbox is checked.
This is working but the code give: "**Undefined index: simple_news_checkbox_css**"

```
$options = get_option( 'simple_news_settings' );

if ( 1 == ! $options['simple_news_checkbox_css'] ) {

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hjemmesider_news_register_plugin_styles');
    function hjemmesider_news_register_plugin_styles() {
    wp_register_style('news', plugins_url('simple-news/css/news.css'));
    wp_enqueue_style('news');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `get_option` gets you the value of your option.

I don't know anything about the specific option or the way it's configured. But basic knowledge of PHP suggests to me that the option `simple_news_settings` doesn't have an array key of `simple_news_checkbox_css` in some cases. So PHP is telling you the array doesn't have the key (or index, as that's the language of the error). An `isset($options['simple_news_checkbox_css'])` check before you try to access the value would stop PHP from complaining.